# Monogame - Sprite sheet animation

Tags: c#, xna, sprites, monogame

I have a sprite sheet that contains a character walk cycle, and I have made a player class that allows the player to move and cycle through the walk animation, however the animation only works whilst walking to the right. I use the arrow keys to move up, down, left and right, meaning when I press any key, my player moves in the correct direction, but only performs the **animation of walking to the right**.

The current animation that works, has been called like this in the `LoadContent()` function:

```
spritesheet = Content.Load<Texture2D>("sprites2");

player = new Player(spritesheet, new Rectangle(0, 96, 32, 48), 
new Vector2(100, 100), 4);
```

This does its job, as it calls each 4 sprites to complete the walking animation to the right, and `new Rectangle(0,96,32,48)` is the location cut out from the sprite sheet. However I need (for example) `new Rectangle(30, 101, 65, 52)` to be used also, which will correctly animate my character when the left arrow key has been pressed.

My question is, how would I get another location of the sprite sheet loaded, and then actually work when I press the correct key?

This is a very difficult question to ask and I very much apologize if it was difficult to understand. Accepting all edits to my question, and thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very high-level thought would be to separate your sprite-sheet into different sheets for each direction so that on different key-presses you can specify which sheet to cycle through, and then you don't need to worry about confusing offsets

Comment: This is a very inefficient solution. What if you want the character to do a jumping animation? Soon you'll end up with tons of animation sheets for a single character- basically removing the reason to have a spritesheet in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

Store your animations in an animation dictionary. You can use a `Dictionary<string,Rectangle[]>` or create a more elaborate construction that holds more frame information (rectangle, timing, offsets).

So you have a dictionary like this (all pseudo code):

```
Animations["walk_right"]=new Rectangle[4]{new Rectangle(0,0,10,10), ... }
```

Keep in your character object the current animation and the timing.

```
 if(walking_to_right)
     current_animation="walk_right";  
 if(walking_to_left)
     current_animation="walk_left";  

 //-- do the timing stuff
```

then in the draw:

```
 spriteBatch.Draw(spritesheet,position,animation[current_animation][frame]);
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible approach would be to have one animation per row, and then the desired row could be passed in based on the direction.